# Grounds Slots booking in flutter(Get) firebase app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, slots

Project: Sports Ground Booking
I want to show the date, slots, and rate for a respected date in ground details where the user can book slots respected to date and which slots are booked, those slots will be
disabled for booking. And how to add data in Firebase I've ground collection where all details are stored. In the Ground Owner app Owner can add grounds, I added ground through the owner and show to the user, but I don't understand how to add slots and show them to the user for booking. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem or give code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.